# OpenGL/C++ Incorrect Pixels are Being Rendered

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I've been making a basic game with OpenGL for the first time.  However, I have run into a problem where when loading in a sprite and then rendering it, which is that once in a while a few extra pixels get added, where it should be transparent or showing the background.

Here is my texture code:

```
#include "texture.h"

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "stb_image.h"
#include <iostream>

Texture::Texture()
{

}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &_texture);
}

void Texture::Init(const std::string& filename)
{
    int width, height, numComponents;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filename.c_str(), &width, &height,
                                    &numComponents, 4);
    if (data == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Unable to load texture: " << filename << std::endl;

    glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height,
                 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    stbi_image_free(data);
}

void Texture::Bind(unsigned int unit)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
}

void Texture::DelTexture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &_texture);
}
```

EDIT: This is the code that I use to render the player:

```
#include "Player.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

Player::Player(std::string texLocation)
{
    Vertex vertices[] = { 
        Vertex(glm::vec3(0.0033325 * 9, 0.0033325 * 14, 0.0f),
        glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(0.0033325 * 9, -0.0033325 * 14, 0.0f),
        glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.0033325 * 9, -0.0033325 * 14, 0.0f),
        glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.0033325 * 9, 0.0033325 * 14, 0.0f),
        glm::vec2(1.0f,  0.0f))
};

    _mesh.Init(vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));
    _texture.Init(texLocation);
}

Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::Bind(Texture* tex)
{
    tex->Bind(0);
}

void Player::BindHealth()
{
    _heTexture.Bind(0);
}

void Player::Render()
{
    _mesh.Draw();
}
```

And this problem only occurs once in a while, and I have only noticed it on the player.

Answer (score 0):

Take out`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)` and `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)` and report what happens.

Comment: Nothing Seems to have changed, however I should also add that this only happens if you move away from the center of the screen.  Also, I just noticed that it is only happening to the top part of the sprite, which is the head.

Comment: Is the image formatted properly? ie I've had issues before with ppm files and setting the alpha channel correctly for each of my colors. Are some parts appropriately transparent, or is it rendering everything incorrectly?
What is the code for stbi_load?

Comment: The image format I'm using is PNG, and everything else seems to be working fine, I also forgot to mention that it doesn't always occur.  And here is the link to the image loader, stbi_image.h that has the stbi_load: https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h